# how to set this s on file permission?

Tags: linux

I need to create a file with the following permission

```
srw-rw-rw- 1 own group 0 Feb  6 22:12 myfile
```

I know chmod 666 would create the 'rw's, but what command to use to create the first s?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As vjayalakshmi points out, the first character is the file type (normal, directory, fifo, socket, etc). `chmod +s` just sets the setuid/setgid bits.  These bits imply executability, which is why `ls` puts the 's' where the 'x' would usually go - it tells you two things with one character (executable, plus set user/group id), giving you the `-rwsrwsrw-` result you are seeing after trying +s with `chmod`.  IOW, `chmod` does exactly what it's name implies - it sets the file *access modes*, which have nothing to do with *file type*.

Normally, to create a socket you'd want to do it in a program (i.e. use the `socket(2)` system call).

If you really want to create a socket from the command line (and, of course, depending on what you are trying to do), you can try using the `nc` command.  Also, Tcl has a `socket` command - see http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.4/TclCmd/socket.htm for more info.

Comment: Yes according to documentation. nc would create a socket file. My machines doesn't have nc. I might need to install nc-1.84-22.el6.x86_64 to get it.

Comment: `nc` is also called `netcat`

Comment: How to set permissions **srw-rw-rw-** using chmod(<digit><digit><digit>) ?

Answer (score 4):

The first bit in the file permission is about the file type. The file that you are creating should be of entry type socket to have that s character in the first bit.
Refer this link http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/explain-the-nine-permissions-bits-on-files/

> The Entry Type
>
> There are total 10 bits -rw-r--r--: The file mode printed under the -l
>   option consists of the entry type (1st bit) and the permissions (9
>   bits). The entry type character describes the type of file, as
>   follows:
>
> - Regular file. b Block special file (stored in /dev). c Character special file (stored in /dev). d Directory. l Symbolic link. p FIFO. s
>     Socket. w Whiteout.

Comment: Yes. I think It is a Unix Domain Socket.